# What is the origin of the word "Arzt"?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the German word *Arzt*? This expression is used to designate a  medical doctor. I have researched the equivalent in English (Doctor), in Italian (Dottore), and in Spanish - my native language (Doctor). There are many similarities between them, but not in the case of German.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Would you mind to include your found similarities that it becomes more obvious what you mean with "not in the case of German". Thanks.

Comment: Hi Martin. Good questions in this forum display a certain amount of own research done to solve the question. There are etymological dictionaries. What do they say?

Comment: Dutch has both "arts" and "dokter" FWIW, as do some other languages - one word that relates to "doctor" and one more localised.

Answer (score 16):

You are looking for the [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology) of the word 'Arzt'. Once you know what you're looking for, Google is a quick helper. According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Arzt#Etymology), the word dates back to ancient Greece, but some people might argue that wiktionary itself is not a good source. However, other pages such as [etymologeek](https://etymologeek.com/deu/Arzt) agree on this:

> German word Arzt comes from Ancient Greek ἰατρός, Ancient Greek ἀρχι-, and later Latin archiater (Physician, especially a chief physician of a ruler.).

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Arzt) has a more precise derivation

> Arzt m. ‘Fachmann auf dem Gebiet der Medizin, der Kranke heilt’, ahd. arzāt (9. Jh.), mhd. arzāt, arzet, mnd. arste, mnl. arsatere (nl. arts aus hd. Arzt) sind Entlehnungen aus mlat. arciater, spätlat. archiāter, archiātrus, griech. archiātrós (ἀρχιατρός) ‘Ober-, Leibarzt’, aus griech. arch(i)- (ἀρχ(ι)-) ‘Ober-, Haupt-, Erz-’ (s. ↗Architekt) und iātrós (ἰατρός) ‘(Wund)arzt’.

So *Arzt* probably started from Greek archiatros (*main-doctor*) which was adopted by Latin (*archiatrus* -> *arciater*) which was loaned by Old High German (*arzat*) before it finally became *Arzt*. So as mentioned by [guidot](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1696/guidot) in the comments, the word Arzt seems to relate to the main (greek *archi*) responsible person for healing.

The word Doktor is also used in German. However, as the English equivalent, this generally refers to a person who has obtained a PhD degree. So doctor is rather an academic title than a job description (at least in German). However, because almost every Arzt has written a "PhD"-thesis, many people use it synonymously.

In German, if you refer to the profession, you always say "Er ist Arzt". Doktor doesn't work here. In my experience, especially when talking to children, the word Doktor is used more often, sometimes in conjunction with uncle: "Da müssen wir mal zum Onkel Doktor gehen."

Comment: "Er ist Doktor" works in my opinion - though it is perhaps a bit less formal, and doesn't necessarily disclose whether he's an "Arzt-Doktor" or of any other profession.

Comment: After looking at [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Arzt) this seems somewhat imprecise, since old high German *arzāt* from middle latin *arciater* only use the prefix but ignores the ἰατρός stem. So *Arzt* is more related to *Erz-* from *Erzbischof*.

Comment: Thanks, I included this.

Comment: Hmmm.  Demzufolge ist der Oberarzt der "Oberchef Doktor."

Comment: Thank you. Fixed it

Comment: @guidot Why are you ignoring the *-at* of *arzat*?

Comment: @DavidVogt, without looking at the link i suppose guidot refers to an older written form *arz*. However, as *z* came to be called *tzet* representing /ts/ I think that the objection is immaterial. /arts/ ~ /artst/ is a reasonable apocope. At least I was quite surprised relatively late learning it should not be spelled *?Artzt*.